# Delphi Procedure/Function Creation help

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to make a function to clean up a bit of my code...

instead of having to use a crap ton of FOR loops to do this....

```
Form1.Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile();
Form1.Image2.Picture.LoadFromFile();
Form1.Image3.Picture.LoadFromFile();
Form1.Image4.Picture.LoadFromFile();
```

is theres a way to do something like this

```
procedure UpdateCardImage(Value,Value2,ImageX : Integer);
var
i,i2 : integer;
begin

for i := 2 to Value do
begin
for i2 := 98 to Value2 do
begin
if Value2 = 99 then
begin
Form1.Image[ImageX].Picture.LoadFromFile('images\' + IntToStr( i + 30 - 5) + '.JPG');
end;
if Value2 = 100 then
begin
Form1.Image[ImageX].Picture.LoadFromFile('images\' + IntToStr( 13 -1 + i ) + '.JPG');
end;
if Value2 = 104 then
begin
Form1.Image[ImageX].Picture.LoadFromFile('images\' + IntToStr(i -1 ) + '.JPG');
end;
if Value2 = 115 then
begin
Form1.Image[ImageX].Picture.LoadFromFile('images\' + IntToStr(i + 40 -2) + '.JPG');
end;
end;
end;
```

also

delphi gives a error saying 'Undefined Identifier : 'Image';

Comment: In future, please report any errors up front otherwise people will probably assume that your code compiles and runs

Comment: It would be interesting to know what you want this code to do. What is the purpose of the for loops? If you use the fix from @Abelisto, it looks like you are loading jpg files to the same Image multiple times.

Answer (score 4):

Form1.Image1 is not equivalent for Form1.Image[1]
In your case you must use something like
(Form1.FindChildControl('Image' + IntToStr(ImageX)) as TImage).Picture.LoadFromFile();

Comment: ding ding ding we haz a winner!

Comment: @Bryan - This is because `FindChildControl` searches for a `TWinControl`, documentation should mention it. You can easily adapt the function to loop through the `Controls` array though.

Answer (score 1):

The if statement is the problem. Try to make a function that calculates or returns the filename, so you can just go

```
for i:=0 to 100 do
  Form1.Image[ImageX].Picture.LoadFromFile('images\' + GetFilename(i));
```

Even if you have to make an array of filenames and index into it that's better than a loop with if/case statement.

```
const cFilenames : array[0..2] of string = ('one','two','three')
for i:=low(cFilenames) to high(cFilenames) do
  Form1.Image[ImageX].Picture.LoadFromFile('images\' + cFilenames[i]);
```

Comment: no its not a problem... delphi gives me a undefined identifier issue
@ Image[ImageX]

Comment: @Bryan: Do you have an Image[] property on the form? Something that looks like "property Image[index:integer]:TImage read GetImage write SetImage;"?? You should add that error to your question.

Comment: no i don't.......i tryed to add it and got 

Build
  [Error] Unit1.pas(38): Published property 'Image' cannot be of type ARRAY
  [Error] Unit1.pas(38): Field or method identifier expected
  [Error] Unit1.pas(38): Field or method identifier expected

Comment: You can't publish it - it has to be public/protected/private.

Comment: Unit1.pas(38): Field or method identifier expected [Error] Unit1.pas(38): Field or method identifier expected still get that as private/public

Answer (score 0):

May be a code like :

```
procedure UpdateCardImage(Value,Value2,ImageX : Integer);
var
i,i2 : integer;
bFile : bolean;
sFileName : string;
begin
  for i := 2 to Value do
    for i2 := 98 to Value2 do
    Begin
      bFile := true;
      Case Value2 of 
        99  : sFileName := IntToStr( i + 30 - 5);
        100 : sFileName := IntToStr( 13 -1 + i );
        115 : sFileName := IntToStr(i + 40 -2);
      else bFile := False;
      end;
      if bFile then Form1.Image[ImageX].Picture.LoadFromFile('images\' +sFileName+ '.JPG');
    end;
end;
```

Comment: I think what you guys aren't grasping is the fact that...Image[ImageX] is the problem ... delphi gives a error saying  'Undefined Identifier : 'Image'; which i probably should of stated.... im tired very tired...

Comment: thanks for reminding me of case statements :-p its been a while since ive coded

Answer (score 0):

Ok well I was up for 29 or so hours straight when i posted this...Sorry

I found my own solution with a bit of Philnext's help

```
procedure UpdateCardImage(Value,Value2 : Integer; ImageX : String);
var
i,i2 : Integer;
sFileName : string;
bFile : boolean;
begin
 for i := 2 to Value Do
  for i2 := 98 to Value2 Do
    Begin
      bFile := true;
Case Value2 of
  99 : sFileName := IntToStr( i + 30 - 5);
  100 : sFileName := IntToStr(13 -1 + i );
  104 : sFileName := IntToStr( i -1 );
  115 : sFileName := IntToStr(i + 40 -2);
   else bFile := False;
   end;
   if bFile then
   begin
    if ImageX = 'Image1' then
    Form1.Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('images\' +sFileName+ '.JPG');
    if ImageX = 'Image2' then
    Form1.Image2.Picture.LoadFromFile('images\' +sFileName+ '.JPG');
    if ImageX = 'Image3' then
    Form1.Image3.Picture.LoadFromFile('images\' +sFileName+ '.JPG');
    if ImageX = 'Image4' then
    Form1.Image4.Picture.LoadFromFile('images\' +sFileName+ '.JPG');
    if ImageX = 'Image5' then
    Form1.Image5.Picture.LoadFromFile('images\' +sFileName+ '.JPG');
    if ImageX = 'Image6' then
    Form1.Image6.Picture.LoadFromFile('images\' +sFileName+ '.JPG');
    if ImageX = 'Image7' then
    Form1.Image7.Picture.LoadFromFile('images\' +sFileName+ '.JPG');
  end;
 end;
end;
```

Abelisto had a interesting answer that would look like it would work but didn't...Props for the suggestion Abelisto.

Answer (score 0):

OK Bryan ... I didn't really see the problem.

The best way seems to be :

```
   if bFile then
   begin
     Form1.TImage(FindComponent(ImageX)).Picture.LoadFromFile('images\' +sFileName+ '.JPG');
   end;
```

I suppose that Form.Image[x] is a TImage, tou need to add the Tcomponent Library in the code.
See the help for FindCompoent.